# Eunning JsTestDriver server from Eclipse plugin

Tags: javascript, eclipse, js-test-driver

I have eclipse Juno (a new install) and installed the JsTestDriver plugin 1.3.4.e.  I have one project, sandbox, with src, lib, and src-test directories; I have JsTestDriver's example files: *Greeter.js* in src, *GreeterTest.js* in src-test.  My *jsTestDriver.conf* is:

```
server: http://localhost:42442

load:
  - src/*.js
  - src-test/*.js

test:
  - src-test/*.js
```

And this is in the 'sandbox' project folder. I have gone to Windows / Preferences and set the (same) port number and a path to Internet Explorer.

When I click on the green triangle to run the server, it does something for 15-20 seconds with a 'wait' cursor, and then I get a "JS Test Driver" error dialog saying "Reason: Error starting the server on 42442".

I can run the JsTestDriver example from the command line; I set default directory to the sandbox folder, run the server by specifying the lib directory for the jsTestDriver.jar, and from a different CMD window run the tests, that seems to work for the one test I have.  I have to kill eclipse first, since evidently its error leaves the server running and therefore the port is occupied.

So first I would like to know what I'm doing wrong that my eclipse plugin doesn't work.

Second I would like to know how to terminate the server without killing the entire eclipse IDE.